# Exact interpretration of p-value and significance of test

Tags: statistics

**First question:**

Let's say we have a hypothesis test:

${ H }_{ 0 }:u=100$
and ${ H }_{ 1 }:u\neq 100$.

The sample has a size of 10 and gives an average $u=103$ and a p-value = 0.08.
The level of significance is 0.05.

I'm asked the following question (exam):

A) We can conclude that $u=100$

B) We cannot conclude that $u\neq100$

The 2 answers are rather similar, but not the same. I would say B) but I'm not so sure given what I've read.

The p-value here indicates that we cannot reject the null hypothesis, so we cannot accept H1 ?

**Second question:**

What does it mean exactly that a test is significant ?

Does it mean that we can reject the null hypothesis ?

Thanks in advance.

Regards,

Answer (score 4):

A hypothesis test in the frequentist sense is a procedure by which one arrives at a decision about whether the data contains sufficient evidence to accept the alternative hypothesis.  In other words, there are two choices:  either you reject the null $H_0$, or the test is inconclusive.

The reason why you cannot ever "accept the null" under such a test is because the test statistic and the resulting $p$-value are calculated under the distributional assumption that the null is true.  Therefore, a $p$-value that is not sufficiently small (i.e., smaller than the $\alpha$ level) is somewhat tautological:  it essentially says that, assuming the data indeed is drawn from a distribution that follows the null hypothesis, the probability of seeing a sample as extreme as that you obtained is $p$.  If $p$ is "large," that doesn't mean $H_0$ is true, because you *assumed* that it was true in order to get $p$ in the first place.

All that you can say if you fail to reject $H_0$ is that the data does not furnish enough evidence to suggest with a high degree of confidence that $H_0$ is false.

Another way to think of it is this:  suppose I give you a coin and you wish to test if it is biased.  If you toss it 10 times and observe 5 heads and 5 tails, that does not necessarily mean that it is in fact fair--you could have observed this result from a biased coin purely due to random chance.  All you can say is that the result you obtained does not furnish strong evidence that the coin is biased.

Comment: Nice contribution. So according to you, answer should be B) ?

Answer (score 2):

Aren't you also given either the population or sample deviation? If any of these are given,  you assume the data is distributed a certain way, e.g., normally, with $\mu=100, \sigma=\sigma_0$. Knowing this, i.e., the (assumed) parameters of the population you are sampling from, then allows you to compute the probability of obtaining the value of 103 under this distribution (say , but not neccesarily, normal) $\mu=100, \sigma=\sigma_0$. If the probability of this value 103 is less than , say,(the significance level) 5% , then you reject ;otherwise you do not reject.

So rejecting a hypothesis at a significance level of k% given the assumption $\mu=\mu_0$, given some value s for either the sample deviation , when the sample mean is $\mu_2$ just means that  the probability of obtaining a value of $\mu_2$ in a population with mean $\mu_0$ and deviation s is less than $k$%. Of course there are variants of this test for different parameters.

As above poster wrote, if the p-value-- the probability of observing the value you observed-- is less than the significance value/level, then you reject , but you reject at the given significance value/level. The explanation for what is going on is in the above paragraphs ; let me know if it was not clear.

Comment: I don't have any info about the standard dev. This is just about the interpretation related to the p-value. Any clue ?

Comment: Please see the bottom paragraph I  just wrote and let me know if it answers your question.

Comment: Sorry, I misread ;let me add something.

Comment: No: the p-value > 0.05 here.

Comment: Right, then you do not reject. But you do not conclude the mean is 100; the sample data may have been either unrepresentative or made up of outliers. You can only conclude that under assumptions (which you cannot guarantee) of data being representative (not outliers ) and randomly-selected, the claim is true.

Comment: So you conclude answer B ?

Comment: Phrasing is confusing. I would say we  conclude/assume the mean is 100, but we cannot be 100% sure that this is the case.

Comment: Yes it is confusing. Since the nb of observations is low (10), I think the right answer should be B ?

Comment: But the number of observations is factored in the p-value already.

Comment: oh ok. So we're now both to be confused.

Comment: p-value normally indicates the plausibility that the null hypothesis is correct, not that it is correct, which leads me to think that the answer is B not A. Your opinion?

Comment: It is always an issue of plausibility; you can never reach absolute certain, but it is more plausible/likely , given the sample data and the distribution, that the mean is actually 100.

Answer (score 1):

A P-value can be reported more formally in terms of a fixed level α test. Here α is a
number selected independently of the data, usually 0.05 or 0.01, more rarely 0.10. We
reject the null hypothesis at level α if the P-value is smaller than α , otherwise we fail to
reject the null hypothesis at level α.

Now figure out what you have to do?
.

Comment: Sorry, but I already know that. I know that I cannot reject the null hypothesis here. But does it mean that we can conclude that Ho=100 ??? This is the real question. Or can we just conclude that we cannot accept the alternative.

Comment: We fail to reject the null hypothesis and there is weak evidence against the null hypothesis in favor of the alternative hypothesis and in general what you hope to conclude as a result of the experiment should be placed in the alternative hypothesis and hence I would say the answer is cannot conlude $u\ne 100$